# Power cycle causing DMA interrupt failure on 50% of the received MCUs

Tags: microcontroller, atmel

To start with, I've had an open discussion with Microchip since July and I'm not really any closer to understanding what the issue is.

We are using the ATSAML21J/ATSAML21E

The issue goes like this:

Step 1: Program the board with a barebones tester that has a DMA interrupt set to fire when enough ADC samples are collected, toggle a pin at the start and end of capturing, retrigger

Step 2: Power cycle (NOT reset, issue doesn't occur with resets)

Step 3: The pin toggles indicating that the interrupt fired is no longer present

Step 4: Bang head on desk because this only happens with 50% of the microcontrollers (a task with our production is to clear these boards, out of 100 fresh boards, 50% have this issue)

Step 5: Erase the board, reprogram, works again as intended

I have tried code where it doesn't even do anything, it just goes straight into the system off mode and it still fails.

The only big hint that I've now found is that when the exact same code is compiled with GCC 6.3.1 (instead of 10.3 like I originally was using) the issue is now resolved on the J series boards, but NOT the E series boards.

I am obviously very confused and would love to find a way to place the blame on the manufacturer.

One hint I've been able to deduce related to the J series:

Step 1: Program with "bad firmware" (ARM embedded 10.3)

Step 2: Remove power for 10 seconds

Step 3: Reconnect power, observe the DMAC is now no longer firing

Step 4: Without erasing, reflash it with the good firmware (6.3.1)

Step 5: Confirm that the DMAC issue is still present

This tells me the "bad" firmware is setting a fuse I can't find access to and erasing it fixes it.

I'd love to switch microcontrollers but we have purchased a lot already. I'd also like to avoid having to rewrite/perform board bring up again. This was very hair pulling to figure out as simple resets simply do not cause this issue.

Comment: What exactly does `toggle a pin` mean? Is it in a known state before? Do you put out 010 or 101? Did you send Microchip a sample of boards, did they report their results?

Comment: One universal troubleshooting technique in computer programming - delete stuff from your firmware until it starts working or something changes. Then you know the problem is related to the last thing you deleted. You could also diff the assembly code of both versions of the firmware (a task that is a lot easier if you delete as much as possible beforehand). Perhaps you could try mixing and matching the two compilers e.g. delete all the code from a function and replace it with the inline assembly code generated by the *other* compiler.

Comment: @greybeard

Toggle a pin high to indicate DMAC capture trigger start, toggle it low when the DMAC capture is complete, the result is a very consistent square wave when all good.

We did send them a test fixture and they were able to replicate the issue, but noted that the compiler makes a difference for J boards. We have not sent them an E board and we're still trying to source an E series dev board.

Comment: @user253751

I did an attempt where literally nothing starts, right out of the reset handler, go straight into a power off "sleep mode". This was very disappointing as I thought I could catch it with a brown out detector and use the "off sleep mode" as an emergency fallback state.

I will try the assembly code approach and digging through the startup portions to understand if there's a difference.

Comment: @ARoss I don't understand how going into sleep mode right after starting up would help you diagnose an ADC/DMA interrupt problem?

Comment: I have hardly any information but I am 95% sure that there's a problem with the program - because it's *always* a programming problem. It's very rare that a problem like this is a chip problem, or a compiler problem.

Comment: Have both compiler versions generate assembly files, stare down the diffs. Diff the header files, watch out for (missing) `volatile`s.

Comment: @user253751 Normal startup is to configure all the peripherals, etc. this startup is nothing. Literally power on, enter system off mode. With that happening it means that it's not anything in my application, it has to be in startup or in the state when it's shutting down. The power being removed still is triggered without setting up anything. Essentially it rules out my application code because nothing is ever actually run.

Comment: @greybeard I'll try this out right now. It was a mind blown moment when the 6.3.1 compiler produced code that worked when the 10.3.1 did not. Nothing code wise changed.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PlGycKwnsSw

This has me very suspicious that we have potentially rejected chips. We got them from Digikey so I highly doubt it, but it seems like this stuff can happen (especially with the electronic market we're in now)

Comment: Possibly, but until you narrow down the problem, it's *much* more likely to be a problem with the code.

Comment: (Version 6 = compiler 6.3.1, version 10 = 10.3)

Test:


`Flash program 10 -> remove power -> no erase, flash version 6-> issue still persists`



`Flash program 6 -> remove power -> no erase, flash version 6 -> issue not present`


This is indicating that something in the "bad firmware" is leaving a lingering issue somewhere in memory, which might not be the flash memory section/fuses if the read is to be trusted.

I am going to hunt to see if I can erase everything but flash on startup and see if that helps. Erasing before programming clears the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is still sort of a frustrating one but I determined that the issue was in the SAML21's low power SRAM. By clearing it to 0 manually in the Reset_Handler all issues were resolved.

simply:

void Reset_Handler(void)
{
memset((const void *)0x30000000, 0u, 2000u);
...